Dispose not called on child components in Blazor
I have a parent component that implements IDisposable, where I have a child component called MyGrid. Now MyGrid extends Syncfusion's SfGrid which itself implements IDisposable. When I close the parent component its Dispose method is called but Dispose inside MyGrid isn't called. Is it normal ? I thought Dispose had like a chain effect. Should I explicitly call Dispose on MyGrid (after getting a reference to it)?
Parent.razor :
<MyGrid ... />

MyGrid.cs :
public class MyGrid<T> : SfGrid<T>
{
    ...

    public override async void Dispose()
    {
       await PersistDataAsync();
    }
}


How about you call base.Dispose() in your overriden method (after the await PersisDataAsync() call)? You override the base method thus broke the chain disposable chain.

When the base class makes it overridable then this is where base.Dispose() is mandatory. But the  async here is scary. This is not the place to save stuff.

I think you need to use DisposeAsync. It was introduced in dotnet8. Using it can be a little tricky:

if your MyGrid is a sealed component (you do not need to write other components which inherit from MyGrid), the task is easy:

public sealed class MyGrid<T> : SfGrid<T>, IAsyncDisposable
{
...
    public ValueTask DisposeAsync() => PersistDataAsync();
}


if your MyGrid is not a sealed class, there are some complexities implementing it.

I strongly suggest you to read Implement a DisposeAsync method.
P.S. I completely agree with Henk. Persisting data in Dispose is not considered best practice. Exercise caution when doing that.
